# Multiple instances of WordPress index.php running?

Tags: wordpress

I seem to be dealing with DoS attacks or something and I'm not sure how to resolve this.

My server will start running slow, and when I look at the current processes running I see something like this...

[image]

Each of those is chewing up 4% of the CPU, and they keep piling on, and the CPU usage actually keeps growing.

Sometimes they will all go away again and things will run smoothly again after a few moments, but other times it ends up killing the server response and I have to restart the service.

I'm on the latest version of WordPress with only a few plugins installed like Google Analytics, WordPress SEO, Gravity Forms, WooCommerce, etc.  Nothing that should be giving me any problems.  All plugins are up-to-date.

My hosting company isn't being much help trying to figure out why this is happening.  They just keep saying it's a WP problem.

Any information on how I can resolve this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you disable all plugins?

Comment: Well, it's happening sporadically, so it's tough to say.  As of right this moment everything looks good and I don't see any of those processes running even though I'm actively browsing the site.  It's a live site so it's going to be hard to disable all the plugins and wait to see what happens.  Any other way to troubleshoot?

Comment: Download it and set up a dev/test environment

Comment: I have a test environment and the problem isn't happening there with all the same plugins.